# Arrays undefined vs -1

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

Why is there a difference between these two outputs in say this code:

```
var animals = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

console.log = [4];
console.log(animals.indexOf("e"));
```

As in, why does it say undefined vs -1 at indexOf?

Comment: in console.log = [4] you are assigning log key of console object to an array [4]  ( by default console.log is assigned a function that logs to console)

Comment: `animals` is a typo. Correct one should be `animal`.

Comment: and you are using two different arrays animal and animals

Comment: What are you trying to do with `console.log = [4]`? Did you mean `console.log([4])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexOf() looks for "e" in the array. If it is found it will return the position it is at,  otherwise it will always return -1.

console.log = [4] is assigning [4] to console.log, which overrides the function console.log() and assigns it the value of an array with one value, 4.

Answer (score 0):

It should be written like this (with all errors corrected):

```
var animal = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
console.log(animal.indexOf("e"));
```

Now it works.